# Roku with Instant TV Channel and BrightScript Differences

Tags: channel, television, roku, brightscript, instant

I am a beginner for developing an app for Roku platform. I had few queries on instant tv channel and the BrightScript.

1. I tried installing the BrightScript plugin in eclipse to start with the Roku app development. I have CDN which provides set of web services which i can consume to show the videos or the content.
2. I have also created the account in Instant tv channel which takes inputs as URLs and easily I can create the channel and upload to the Roku app dev store.

Here my question is that

1. whether I should go ahead with BrightScript programming language for app development ?
2. Or Instant tv channel setup is better for creating my channels ?
3. Why people choose BrightScript instead of Instant TV Channel ? would like to know the Pros and cons of these two ways..

I might be wrong in understanding the usage of these. How can I develop the app for Roku Platform?

I have referred : http://forums.roku.com/ forums , http://www.instanttvchannel.com/roku/quick to understand the differences between these two techniques of developing the Roku app. I have also followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQzk_Iq9dYI&feature=youtu.be to understand the app development and created the app.

Also Eclipse+ BrightScript plugin integration i did by following the http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Eclipse+Plugin+Guide link

Comment: Hi Bhat 
How do you test Roku app? Can single app work on multiple Roku devices (as Roku sells multiple devices)?

Comment: This question is (and was) too broad for Stack Overflow. I will try to close it as Needs More Focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used instant tv, but basically Brightscript means that you have full control (relatively) over your app.

Comment: thans @Morgan LaVigne